# What will happen if we remove the hypothesis that $V$ is finite-dimensional in this problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Original problem:

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $S, T,U ∈L(V)$and $STU = I$. Show that T is invertible and that $inv(T) = US$.

I know that it is because of the hypothesis of finite-dimensional that we can take advantage of the basis or spanning list of vectors. But I'm not quite clear of the power of "Finite-Dimensional" in linear algebra.

Please help me with some examples and insights.
Really really appreciate it.

Comment: What is $(L, V)$?  A lot of things are true in finite dimensional spaces that are not true in more general spaces.  One surprising example, one of my favorites, is that the unit ball is compact in a finite dimensional space, but is not compact in an infinite dimensional one.  One consequence of this is that continuous functions do not necessarily attain a maximum on the unit ball in infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that mistake, it should have been $L(V)$

Comment: What is $L(V)$?  I assume $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and that $L(V)$ is something like linear transformations on that space? so that $S, T, U$ are (essentially) just matrices?  Do we know if they are square? i.e. maps from $V$ to $V$?

Comment: $L(V)$ denotes the set of all linear operators on V

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely false in infinite dimensions.

Let $V$ be an vector space of countably infinite dimension, and pick a basis $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ for $V$.

Let $T$ be the be the map which sends $v_1 \mapsto 0$ and $v_n \mapsto v_n$ for $n\geq 2$.

Let $U$ be the map which sends $v_n \mapsto v_{n+1}$.

Let $S$ be the map which sends $v_1 \mapsto 0$ and $v_n \mapsto v_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$.

Then $STU=I_V$ but $T$ is not invertible since nothing maps to $v_1$ under $T$.

Comment: Note the strength of Shalop's argument: for **any** infinite-dimensional vector space, such $S, T, U$ exist! (It doesn't even need to be countable dimension - we can do the same trick for a basis of any size, by restricting to a countable subset of the basis and leaving the rest alone.) So the theorem in fact is a *characterization* of "finite-dimensional."

Comment: Oh yeah. I hadn't even noticed that... :)

Answer (score 2):

It fails in general:

Let $V$ be the vector space - over the reals - of infinite sequences of reals (so an element of $V$ is of the form $a=(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$).

Let $U$ be the transformation $V\rightarrow V$ which "shifts right": $$U(a_0, a_1, a_2, . . . )= (0, a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .).$$

Let $T$ be the transformation $V\rightarrow V$ which "kills the first coordinate": $$T(a_0, a_1, a_2, . . .)=(0, a_1, a_2, . . .).$$

Let $S$ be the transformation $V\rightarrow V$ which "shifts left": $$S(a_0, a_1, a_2, . . .)=(a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .).$$

Then $STU=I$ but $T$ is non-invertible.

Comment: It looks like we have similar ideas :)

Comment: Damn, beat me to it (by 9 seconds :P)!